# Know which Apps to Remove From MSConfig with this Startup Applications List

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, networking, windows-7

Just found userfull information on Internet and thought it would help all of users.
[This list of startup applications](http://www.sysinfo.org/startuplist.php) is a really handy resource for cleaning up msconfig entries that have overtaken old computers. It catalogs tons of different startup programs, what they do, and which ones you should delete, leave running, or decide based on the program's usefulness. It even has a nice search box so you can search through the tens of thousands of entries. Hit the link below to check it out, and if your relatives' computer is especially broken, be sure to check out our guide to fixing your relatives' terrible computer.

http://www.sysinfo.org/startuplist.php

Please update the list here if you got any other tools or sites which can be help full to others

Comment: Found another site 
http://www.pacs-portal.co.uk/startup_content.php

Comment: Nice Post +! for that

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: No, its not the question. This is just for the educational and information purpose.

Answer (score 1):

On a similar note Sysinternals AutoRuns is a most excellent tool for identifying startup programs, lists all drivers and anything else that you might stumble across on any windows system:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902

Well worth adding to the 'Utilities' folder on that memory stick you take everywhere with you.

Run it as administrator and you can turn everything off directly from the interface too.

Answer (score 0):

On this note, when I'm trying to system optimize (usually goes hand in hand with a virus cleanup) I make EXCELLENT use of HijackThis.

The only problem is off the top knowing what all those entries stand for. Alot to remember.

In any case, I run HiJack This to find and isolate unneeded entries in the startup list, BHO objects, and more.

Then I use this website, http://www.hijackthis.de/, do automatically analyze the log file, and provide me with easier to understand results.